# Exact Target SFTP public key authentication

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

We recently changed over to use SFTP instead of FTP with exact targets import/export FTP server.

When we try to log in with our existing FTP credentials, it says wrong authentication method, expecting publickey, and so on.

I've generated some keys using puttygen, however when I tried to upload them using asymmetric key in Encryption Key management, it says that it's an invalid key file.

Any idea how I'm supposed to get the public key for our SFTP?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the only thing required to access the Enhanced FTP as an sFTP is to change your port on your client (Filezilla, etc.) to port 22.  (from port 21).  That's pretty much it.  Same user and password.

If, however, you're interested in connecting to the SFTP via a set of ssh keys, you'll need to generate the key pair, and then call Marketing Cloud support to let them know that you would like to access the FTP via the public key.  You can tell them if you want the key only, or if you still want to be able to use the password as well.

The Key Management section within the Admin tab of Marketing Cloud is for encrypting and decrypting files that reside on the FTP.  So, you're not using that feature for connecting to the server.

Hope that helps!